# Auto complete Text Field

Tags: android, autocomplete, android-edittext, textview

In my app I have a scenario and that is I want to show the user the desired range of numbers and these would be dynamic , let say  1,2,3  or some time ,1,2 or some time 1,2,3,4,5  I want user to select on of the number from my given range. so that I dont want user to fill by typing numbers. Please tell me how to achieve this and How can i control the range of numbers in autocomplete textview .

or what is alternate of this. Just keep in mind I have Edittext , and in that edittext I want user to select the number not just enter the number.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [AutoCompleteTextView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView.html) in your layout:

**XML Code**

```
<AutoCompleteTextView android:id="@+id/EdtSearch"
                      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                      android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

**JAVA Code**
To bind array inside `AutoCompleteTextView` use the following code

```
AutoCompleteTextView EdtSearch = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.EdtSearch);
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, rangesyouwantasStringArray);
EdtSearch.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use a Spinner? I think that for your purposes it is more efficient. 
You can change your EditText to a Spinner and with its adapter, change the range programmatically.

Edit:

Here is the element that you have to insert instead of the edittext

```
<Spinner android:id="@+id/spinner"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Then, in your Activity/Fragment code:

```
Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

// Here add the range of numbers. For example:
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    adapter.add(Integer.toString(i));
}
```